# Two cards drawn - probability

Tags: probability

Two cards are drawn successively from a pack of $52$ cards. Find the probability that the cards are picture cards (Jack,Queen and King), or spades, or both.

I did the normal $A \cup B$ formula, but then I realised that this will fall under conditional probability. I don't have any formula for that though.

Comment: What's the probability that the first drawn card is of the form you want?  Conditioned on a success with the first card, what is the probability that the second is also a card of the form you want?

Comment: @lulu is it (22/52)*(21/51)?

Comment: You need to select two out of 22 cards.

Comment: Yes!  and it is good to verify that this gives the same result as the (solid) method proposed by @prog_SAHIL

Answer (score 1):

If neither are spades, they should both be faces and the number of cases is ${\binom{9}{2}}$. If one of them is spade, the other one should either be spade or non-spade face. The former case has ${\binom{13}{2}}$ and the latter has ${\binom{13}{1}\binom{9}{1}}$ number of possible cases which makes a total probability $$\dfrac{\binom{9}{2}+\binom{13}{2}+\binom{9}{1}\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}$$

Comment: I thought you mean two spade faces by **both**.

Comment: So you mean the case $1\heartsuit,K\spadesuit$ is valid huh?